# Powershell always-on-top script

Tags: powershell, winapi

I tried this script :

https://github.com/bkfarnsworth/Always-On-Top-PS-Script

It listed all apps successfully, but I doens't seem to actually make a window on top (I selected a notepad window).

Comment: Please read [ask].

Answer (score 4, accepted):

FYI there exists a standard [Always on Top utility](https://learn.microsoft.com/windows/powertoys/always-on-top) in [Microsoft PowerToys](https://learn.microsoft.com/windows/powertoys/) that can do this.
Anyways, if you need to automate this, you can do this from PowerShell using the [`SetWindowPos` function (winuser.h)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-setwindowpos) where the second argument (`-1`) stands for `TOPMOST`:

```
$User32 = Add-Type -Debug:$False -MemberDefinition '
    [DllImport("user32.dll")] public static extern bool SetWindowPos(IntPtr hWnd, IntPtr hWndInsertAfter, int X,int Y, int cx, int cy, uint uFlags);
' -Name "User32Functions" -namespace User32Functions -PassThru

$Handle = (Get-Process -Name notepad).MainWindowHandle
[Void]$User32::SetWindowPos($Handle, -1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0x53)
```

Comment: an app is not a script you can customize and ingrate with other scripts. It's weird you don't know this : if I wanted an app I would have asked SuperUser Forum instead ;)

Comment: @use Why do you expect an answer? As it stands, you haven't even asked a question. Maybe it's time for you to take the [tour] in addition to reading [ask].