# powershell - Start-Process -wait + always on top (topmost)

Tags: powershell, wait, start-process, topmost

i have the following code:

```
Start-Process -FilePath myprogram.exe -Wait
# ... some other code to be executed AFTER the previous process has ended
```

**What i need**

I need to start the process with `-wait` as you can see, but i also need that that the window of that process to be always on top (or "topmost").

**What i tried**

I've seen this question/answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/73319269

And i've tried what the solution suggests, like this:

```
$User32 = Add-Type -Debug:$False -MemberDefinition '
    [DllImport("user32.dll")] public static extern bool SetWindowPos(IntPtr hWnd, IntPtr hWndInsertAfter, int X,int Y, int cx, int cy, uint uFlags);
' -Name "User32Functions" -namespace User32Functions -PassThru

$proc = Start-Process -FilePath myprogram.exe -Passthru

$Handle = ($proc).MainWindowHandle
[Void]$User32::SetWindowPos($Handle, -1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0x53)
```

But

- it doesn't work, the myprogram.exe window is not topmost
- i had to remove `-wait` to add and utilise `-passthru`, so how can i detect when the execution of myprogram.exe is over?

---

Thank you for your help.

Comment: I guess `myprogram.exe` starts a new child process. You will need to identify that child process (with e.g. the task manager) and `Get-Process` that to be able to wait for it and put it on top.

Comment: @iRon myprogram.exe _is_ the child process, started by powershell. `start-process` with `-passthru` correctly gets its handle. but if i use passthru, i can't use `-wait`, that's my problem

Comment: That doesn't mean that `myprogram.exe` does have a (grand) child itself.

Answer (score 0):

Taking `cmd.exe` for a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example):

```
$User32 = Add-Type -Debug:$False -MemberDefinition '
    [DllImport("user32.dll")] public static extern bool SetWindowPos(IntPtr hWnd, IntPtr hWndInsertAfter, int X,int Y, int cx, int cy, uint uFlags);
' -Name "User32Functions" -namespace User32Functions -PassThru

Start-Process -FilePath cmd.exe
Start-Sleep 1 # wait for the process to initialize
$Proc = Get-Process cmd
$Handle = ($Proc).MainWindowHandle
[Void]$User32::SetWindowPos($Handle, -1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0x53)
Wait-Process $Proc.id
```

Comment: With this code, powershell reports: `Cannot convert argument "hWnd", with value: "System.Object[]", for "SetWindowPos" to type "System.IntPtr": "Cannot convert the "System.Object[]" value of type "System.Object[]" to type "System.IntPtr"."` .  
If i instead get the handle via `$proc = Start-Process -FilePath cmd.exe -Passthru ; $Handle = ($proc).MainWindowHandle`, it doesn't error out. 
*however*, `SetWindowPos` returns *false*, it doesn't work. I tried both with cmd.exe and with an empty c# win form app

Comment: I also tried importing and calling `GetLastError` from kernel32.dll but it returns 0...